tangential sobolev spaces
Let $Ω⊂R^n$ be a Smooth domain, define $U_s=${$x∈Ω | d(x,∂Ω)<s$}; let $f∈W^{1,p}(Ω)∩W_{loc} ^{2,p}(Ω)$; let $v$ be the unit normal to $Ω$; consider $v$ to be smooth with bounded derivatives. Using the notation:
$∇_N f=∇f∙v∈L^p (Ω)$
$∇_T f=∇f-v∇_N f∈(L^p (Ω))^n$
Then we have:
$f∈W^{2,p} (Ω)⇔∇_N f∈W^{1,p} (U_s)$ and $∇_T f∈(W^{1,p} (U_s ))^n$
this theorem is found in "Mathematical Tools for the Navier-Stokes Equations and Related Models Study of the Incompressible" Theorem III.3.14
one way “⇒” it's obvious to me. But the reverse implication is harder. Can somebody please explain it ?
here is my attempt:
Assume $∇_N f∈W^{1,p} (U_s)$ and $∇_T f∈(W^{1,p} (U_s ))^n$ then $∇f∈W^{1,p} (U_s )$ since $∇f=∇_T f+v∇_N f$ and both $∇_T f$ and $v∇_N f$ are smooth enough. Now obviously $∇f∈W^{1,p} (U_s )⇒f∈W^{2,p} (U_s )$.
Now assume further that Ω Is bounded, if this is the case then we can find a compact K such that $Ω/U_s⊂K⊂Ω$; for instance a compact can be the closure of all the points in $Ω$ at distance  from the boundary greater or equal to  $s/2$ . So then using $f∈W_{loc}^{2,p} (Ω)⇒f∈W^{2,p} (K)$. Now since $f∈W^{2,p} (K)∩W^{2,p}(U_s )⇒f∈W^{2,p} (Ω)$. However the assumption $Ω$ bounded is not present in the original theorem, and I can't see  how to proceed.
